# Why does my android application create too many items on Device

Tags: android, items

My self-developed android app create 7 items on Device with the same name, but in Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications there is only one item. All classes of my app have the same package. Can anyone explain for me why?
Thanks you so much.

Comment: are you getting 7 icons..in that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that your problem is your getting 7 app with same names in the device when your installing it.

If this is so, then check the activtity tag in manifest file,it should contain only one action.MAIN ( mentioned below) , if you added this all activities the above scenario can happen. To resolve , remove this tag to all activities except main activity.

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Hope it helps.